# Why on my react web the anchors of social media does not works propertly , and a misterious details it works just when user reload the page?

Tags: reactjs, onclick, href, anchor

```
    When user click, it does not open nothing and once reload the browser the 
    anchor open the url social media and all is fine until user navigate to other 
    page and come back again to Contact page the problem is repeated
```

export const Contact = () => {

```
    return (
            <div className="socialMedia">
                <p className="mb-3">Visítenos en nuestras Redes Sociales</p>
                <ul >
                 <li> 
                    <a  href="https://www.instagram.com/fridartestudio"
                        target="_blank"
                        rel="noreferrer"
                    ><i className="bi bi-instagram" id="inst" ></i></a>
                  </li>

                  <li>
                      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/fridarteestudio"
                      target="_blank"
                      rel="noreferrer"
                    
                    ><i className="bi bi-facebook" id="faceb" ></i></a>
                  </li >
                </ul>
             </div>
    )
```

}

I would like to know how to solve this simple problem with my anchors links social media. thanks by the way

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your code it's actually working fine for me. It's opening the social links and even after I navigate to other page and come back to `Contact` it still worked fine. How about you re-open your project with `npm start`

You can also read this out -

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/creating-a-social-follow-component-in-react

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/18390717/rittika-dev yes I always open my project with npm start and here on localhost it work just when I reload the page as well

Comment: I tried reloading the page and it still worked for me. How about you try using Link from react router instead of anchor tag

Comment: when I use link from react router dom this not accept href, do you understand me ? I should try use the useHref hook from react

Comment: Yes. Link does not allow href you have to use "to" instead